# About customizing blob object URL

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am trying to open a blob object in a new tab, it shows a randomly generated string as the URL and the title of the generated PDF. I want to change the URL to be `about:blank` and put a title for the pdf.

I have tried this :

```
  this.service.getPdfReport(date).subscribe(x=>
  {
  let newBlob = new Blob([x], { type: "application/pdf" });
  const data = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
  window.open(data, '_blank');
  }
```

Update : 
   I also tried this :

```
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(newBlob); 
  var base64data;
  reader.onloadend = function() {
       base64data = reader.result; 
       let filepdf = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' 
       +base64data.substr(base64data.indexOf(',')+1);
       let tab=window.open();
      tab.location.href=filepdf;
     tab.document.title="test.pdf";
}
```

Here, I convert the blob Object to base64 format.Then it will displayed as PDF with `about:blank` as URL but content is not mapped.

Screenshot

[image: OUTPUT]